# Can multi-thread load data infile into the same innodb table improve performance?

Tags: multithreading, file-io, load, innodb

I did a test, seems there is no obvious performance improvement
to insert the same number of rows, 2 concurrent threads almost cost the same time with 1 single thread.

Is there any way to improve load data infile performance? Is multi-thread a wrong approach?

Comment: thank you, Doomster,my server has 2 cpus with 8 cores(each 4 cores) and 32g memory and 1 harddisk, do you think multiple thread will get  higher performance?

Answer (score 2):

Multithreading improves performance if it can increase the parallel use of computing resources. If the file and DB are on the same harddisk, you are probably out of luck. If you load data, compute something heavy and then write to the DB, you might be able to use CPU and HD in parallel. For a test, create one thread to read the input file and a second thread to write to the DB (using fake data for the DB). If that is faster than reading a bit and writing a bit, then multithreading can improve performance. I mention that, because it is far from clear what your test actually did.

Answer (score 1):

If you are confident about the consistency of the data you are bulk loading, you might want to use the following:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
-- do the bulk load
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

This will temporarily disable foreign key checks, making the data insertion way faster. 
Regarding multithreading, try moving to the lowest isolation level for both your threads:

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;
-- bulk load
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ; --default setting
```

Change the last line to whatever is your normal isolation level. Alternatively you could use a temporary variable to store the previous level:

```
SET @tx_isolation_orig = @@tx_isolation;
SET @@tx_isolation = read-uncommited;
-- bulk load
SET @@tx_isolation = @tx_isolation_orig;
```

Further infos:

- [InnoDB foreign key constraints](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html)
- [Isolation levels](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/set-transaction.html)